# Implementing a hash which stores any type using C++

Tags: c++, qt

In a library I am developing I have a class that I want to have a hash storing any kind of data. This is because an algorithm using this library may want to store specific data in the objects of that class.

The class is called "ObjectOfInterest" where I have defined the hash using QT:

```
QHash<QString, void*> properties;
```

Then I have implemented this functions to store information:

```
bool ObjectOfInterest::hasProperty(QString prop) const
{
    return properties.contains(prop);
}

template <class T> const T& ObjectOfInterest::getProperty(const QString prop) const
{
    return *(T *)properties.value(prop);
}

template <class T> void ObjectOfInterest::setProperty(const QString prop, T value)
{
    if (hasProperty(prop)) deletePropertyValue<T>(prop);
    properties.insert(prop, new T(value));
}

//private
template <class T> void ObjectOfInterest::deletePropertyValue(const QString prop)
{
    delete (T *)properties.value(prop);
}
```

Now the question is, when deleting an object of "ObjectOfInterest", how can I delete all values stored in the properties hash? For now I have

```
ObjectOfInterest::~ObjectOfInterest()
{
    //delete other stuff...

    QHash<QString, void*>::iterator i;
    for (i = properties.begin(); i != properties.end(); ++i)
    {
        delete i.value();
    }
}
```

But this is not a solution, as I am not calling the destructor. Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/any.html) an option?

Comment: `deletePropertyValue` should **remove** the value from the QHash. You aren’t doing that.

Comment: QVariant can be made to contain any type. Look at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

Comment: @StoryTeller finally I used boost::any, it is what I needed, thanks.

Comment: @cppguy that can be another solution, but is worse as I must use the macro in every class that I need to use in properties. boost::any is the proper way to do that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph "deletePropertyValue" cannot be used in the destructor as it is a template, and I don't know the properties types when the destructor executes.

Comment: @Javi Well likewise you cannot `delete` a pointer if you don’t know its type. But actually forget that I said anything, my previous comment was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution was using boost::any

```
//ObjectOfInterest.h
public:
    ...
    bool    hasProperty(const string & prop) const;
    void    emplaceProperty(const string & prop, boost::any value);
    void    setProperty(const string & prop, boost::any value);
    template <class T> const T property(const string & prop) const
    {
    return any_cast<T>(properties.at(prop));
    }
...
private:
    ...
    boost::unordered::unordered_map<string, boost::any> properties;
```

---

```
//ObjectOfInterest.cpp
...
bool ObjectOfInterest::hasProperty(const string & prop) const
{
    return properties.find(prop)!=properties.end();
}

void ObjectOfInterest::emplaceProperty(const string & prop, any value)
{
    properties.emplace(prop, value);
}

void ObjectOfInterest::setProperty(const string & prop, any value)
{
    properties[prop] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, instead of using a `void*`, I would either make a wrapper-class, that can hold some other object inside it, or dervice all "object of interest content" from the same base-class. Which one you prefer will be up to you.

The reason I suggest that is that when you come to USE the data, you'll want it to be identifiable, and it seems daft not to help yourself out by having an object-type that will provide the relevant interface to do that.

In other words, if you store something, you want to "label it", so that you know what it is. Like you'd do in your garage, loft or wherever you store things you don't need for the time being, but want to keep for the future. For example, you have a box which says "Old shoes" or "Winter clothes", "baby clothes", "books", etc [unless you are like me, and you just have a bunch of similar boxes, with no idea what's in which one - but that's because my storage isn't done as software].

Comment: Your solution is an option, but I think it is not the best in terms of design, as the algorithms that are using the "ObjectOfInterest" class doesn't create them, only use them and some times they need to write some additional information in them.
In that way, a properties object is the right way to do this, and it seems that boost::any is the right way to do that.